# On Air Canada's website can I see the luggage fees and limits for a flight without filling in my details?

Tags: luggage, online-resources, fees-and-charges, air-canada

I'm looking at a flight from China to Mexico and I'm just checking the rules and prices for now. I'm not ready to commit.

I know many airline websites have hidden fees that they don't show you until as late in the booking process as possible.

I've found the cheapest dates and began the booking process and the site tells me some fees including taxes, but no mention is made whether luggage is included, or how much.

Since Air Canada is not an LCC maybe I have nothing to worry about and luggage is included. But lately every booking I do includes at least one evil price surprise.

How can I find the luggage prices and rules for the flights I found without filling in my personal details to go further into the booking process?

Comment: It used to be like that, flat rate for luggage, until airlines introduced hundreds of fare buckets, types, and thus making the luggage fees n limit per bucket, and thats why instead of giving you a matrix of fees, they just aak you your booking code and details to show you the fees applicable. Emirates has , and like you find, Air Canada might, still have almost flat rates, and thus they dont need your booking code to show you the fees. EDIT:Oops, i misread, you asked CAN I, I thought you said WHY CAN I..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: on second reading, perhaps you made a typo and wanted to ask about [international Air China allowance](https://www.airchina.us/US/GB/info/checked-baggage/international.html).

Original answer: Enter the flight details into this handy [Air Canada page](https://beta.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/checked.html) and it'll show the information you are after.

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: Perfection! For my route it told me ["2nd bag
Free
Tickets issued before June 28, 2016: $70 CAD/USD per direction"](http://imgur.com/a/dVSNo) which seems odd. If I book early I have to pay $70 just for the 2nd bag??

Comment: [No it's definitely Air Canada.](http://imgur.com/a/HcETA)

Comment: OK, OK, reading China to Mexico, Air Canada wasn't my first guess for carrier. My geography must be off, why would you fly to the East Coast if coming from Asia to get to Mexico instead of transiting on the West Coast?

Comment: Turns out they're the cheapest that doesn't go via the US. I would've expected Aeromexico direct or in combination with one of the Chinese carriers, but I was only sightly surprised (-: I'm choosing the cheapest as I have no income during my year off and a couple hundred bucks can go a long way in China or Mexico.